# How Can I use the Bind Method in RXSwift?

Tags: rx-swift

The following sample code throws an error stating

```
No exact matches in call to instance method 'bind'
```

How can I bind the onNext of my publish subject to my observable?

```
let publish = PublishSubject<Void>()
// Error Here
publish.bind(to: myMethod())

func myMethod() -> Observable<Void> {
        return Observable.create{ observer in
            observer.onNext(())
            observer.onCompleted()
            
            return Disposables.create()
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to forward any event from the observable returned by your method to the `PublishSubject` ?

Comment: So what I want is everytime my publish subject emits an onNext event I want to trigger the observable of 'myMethod'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what I want is everytime my publish subject emits an onNext event I want to trigger the observable of 'myMethod'

I'm not sure how to interpret this, but it sounds like you want something like:

```
let publish = PublishSubject<Void>()
let response = publish.flatMap { myMethod() }
response
    .bind(onNext: { print($0) })

func myMethod() -> Observable<Void> {
    Observable.create{ observer in
        observer.onNext(())
        observer.onCompleted()
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

But it all seems rather pointless since all `myMethod()` does is emit a next event.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think the thing was that I couldnt bind(to:) and had to use bind(onNext:) when attempting to bind from a publishSubject

Comment: Either there is a lot you are leaving out or you aren't understanding something. The way `MyMethod()` is written, calling `bind(onNext: { myMethod() ))` will do nothing. It's a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `bind(to:)` method is in the RxCocoa Framework so you need to add `import RxCocoa` in your file.

Then, the observable created by `myMethod` will only be able to emit the event from the `.create` block. You can't use bind on it. If you need an observable with both the events from your subject and from the `myMethod` observable, you can do that :

```swift
let thirdObservable = Observable.merge(publish, myMethod())
```